# Issue with Pinterest Grid and ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, pinterest

someone can help me?

I catching TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined.

I'm using Next.JS

```
import { PinterestGrid, PinterestPinWidget } from 'react-pinterest';

const gutter = 20;

export function Grid() {
  return (
    <PinterestGrid gutter={gutter}>
      <PinterestPinWidget pin="530158187357124374" />
      <PinterestPinWidget pin="356417757989339525" />
      <PinterestPinWidget pin="356417757986524080" />
    </PinterestGrid>
  )
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a library that hasn't been updated in 5 years. You may want to look at other alternatives.